# How to get the content with all attributes of a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, styleddocument

I have a `JTextPane` and on a `ActionEvent`, I want to save the content of the `JTextPane` (with the colors, text  and other attributes) in another class (as a variable). Later on I want to exchange the content of the `JTextPane` with the one of the variable.

I have tried to use:

```
(StyledDocument)myTextPane.getDocument()
```

and

```
myTextPane.getStyledDocument()
```

but both didn't work.

I thought about just give the whole `JTextPane` over, but apperently the pane gets still updated in the other class...

EDIT: I would only use the content to show it (later) in the `JTextPane` again. I won't be saving it in a file or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it depends on EditorKit you use. Each kit has own format to store/load content.

For the simplest case (e.g. if you use HTMLEditorKit) you can use getText()/setText().

If you need own format and would like to store the content yourself read [this](http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial_reader_writer.html)

Also you can try to use the [AdvancedRTFEditorKit](http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html) to store the content as RTF (default RTFEditorKit is limited)

Comment: How would I know what Kit I use?

Comment: myTextPane.getEditorKit()

Comment: Can you provide me a bit more information how I would store the informaton from the Pane into the variable? (Sorry I'm still a noob in java)

Comment: String varToStore=myTextPane.getText();